# Symfony routes not working anymore

Tags: symfony

I have an application been working on for a while with a fully working login and creating new users functionalities, and out of no where i was trying to switch the user -to change the role- i wasnt able to login again. after some digging around the code i found out that 302 code status is being thrown after login and therefor the logging process stopped working.

i had this code in my SecurityController:

```
return new RedirectResponse('/sys-admin/');
```

and changing that code to this :

```
return $this->forward('AppBundle:SystemAdmin:index', array());
```

make it work and i am logged in again but now all my routes stopped working, i mean in my views there are buttons something like :

```
<a href="{{ path('system_admin_client') }}"
                           class="btn pmd-btn-flat btn-default">Go!</a>
```

when i click the button i am logged out and redirected to the login page and in the network tab in any browser i can see that the route `sys-admin/client` have status code 302 since i was logged out.

running `bin/console debug:router` shows me all my routes are there and for this example running `bin/console router:match /sys-admin/client` also shows me a match with the controller and every information.

this is how my routes looks like:

```
app_system_admin:
    prefix: /sys-admin
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/sys_admin.yml"
```

## sys_admin.yml

```
system_admin_client:
    path: /client
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:SystemAdmin:index}
```

I cant figure out to know what went wrong! any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

more info: i am using Symfony 4.0.4  and if i tried to do something like forwarding on any route its working but the redirecting is not.

Comment: Try add `prefix: /sys-admin` into sys-admin.yml. And check your security rules, your router rules looks good.

Comment: @Gedweb The prefix is already added in the parent config file. Yamen Nassif, I think there's a typo in the file's name in your question, it's imported with the name `sys_admin.yml` and below you name it "sys-admin.yml." That's confusing.

Comment: @Philippe-B- not really!! its my mistake i wrote it wrong here, as i said router debugging is seeing the routes!

Comment: @Philippe-B- i fixed it in the question, its just typo here on SOF

Comment: Could you please post the actual path generated by `{{ path('system_admin_client') }}` in your button (the whole <a> tag)?

Comment: @Philippe-B- its /sys-admin/client

Comment: The whole <a> tag would be better. Please add this to your question.

Comment: i am sorry i dont get it, the a tag is already in the question!

Comment: So, what about security config?

Comment: what do you mean ? what about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot of investigating. I am using docker to make the whole app running and for some reason php-fpm logs showed no errors but the error was the php session is being broken because of no access for the user, changing to root user on docker fixed this issue since root had access.

Comment: Did you `chown` to the whole app directory?

Answer (score 0):

The 302 HTTP status code is for a redirection, it's not an error.
It was normal since you returned a `RedirectResponse`.

In my opinion the problem doesn't come from the redirection.
You should put it back and check the user-switching function (or the user itself).
If you do that, don't hardcode the redirection path. Use a Symfony method to generate it, like:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('system_admin_index');
```

Comment: I tried, same thing happened redirection is getting me back to the login page!

Comment: You said it was working before. What did you change exactly and what were you trying to achieve? Are you developing a user switching function or did you just switch user to test your app?

Comment: just switched the user

Comment: and btw, even the old user have the same problem

Comment: How did you switch?

Comment: I reverted the whole project to like (5 commits before) it worked with no idea what went wrong, i will dig into it and add a solution whenever i find it